# How to debug application and also test watch with nodemon

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, nestjs, nodemon

I am working on a NestJS project which is executed with `docker-compose`. Among the many containers that are run by `docker-compose` there is one container in which the application runs with nodemon (allowing me to debug it if necessary) and another container in which unit tests are executed when changes in the code are detected.

Is there a way to execute the application and to run unit tests on code changes on the same container? Is it good practice? This would allow my machine to execute faster, since the whole set of containers is quite heavy on resources and having just one container to run the application and run unit tests on the fly would let me remove the container used just for the unit tests.

The nodemon config file is this:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "nest build && node --inspect=0.0.0.0 ./dist/main.js"
}
```

The unit tests in the second container are executed with `jest --watch`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using one container for both running the app and executing tests. I see no problem with it. Since I'm using `sqlite3` for e2e tests my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.18.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install sqlite3 \
```

Also in `docker-compose.yml` my command for this node container is:

```
command: npm run start:debug-remote
```

because why not. This npm command is:

```
"start:debug-remote": "nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch"
```

In order for the debugger to work you have to expose this port (9229) in `docker-compose.yml` (or in `Dockerfile`) and set it in the `.vscode/launch.json` configuration.

Comment: what does your `start:debug-remote` script do?